# For loop returning result until end (python)

Tags: python, list, range, slice, python-3.5

I am trying to find the largest product of 13 consecutive digits of the large number 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450.

However, my code seems to have gone wrong somewhere and the output for 987 times is the following:
`0 731671765313`
Here is the code in question:

```
num = str('**insert the big number here**')
highest = 0
mylist=[]
for i in range(987):
    n = 0
    m = 12
    product = 1
    mylist=[num[n:m]]
    for x in mylist:
        product *= x
        print(n, product)
    n += 1
    m += 1
```

Any help appreciated as I have spent a long time researching this.

Comment: You reset the values for `n` and `m` on each iteration of the loop. Define them before the `for` loop.

Comment: You say mylist = [num[n:m]], but you should just have mylist = num[n:m]. And also num is a string, so you'll have to use int(x) rather than just x. Otherwise you're doing product *= "9"

Comment: What is your expected output? Currently you just `print` the result, and everything is thrown away. Do you want the sequence of numbers and the generated product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here.

```
num = str('**insert the big number here**')
highest = 0
# No need to declare mylist ahead of time
# Define n and m outside of loop:
n = 0
m = 13 # m should be 13
for i in range(987):
    product = 1
    mylist = num[n:m] # No extra [] here
    for x in mylist:
        product *= int(x) # x is string because num is string, so we must convert to int
    # Checking the product should be outside of the x loop:
    print(n, product)
    # Check if product is highest:
    if product > highest:
        highest = product
    n += 1
    m += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as pointed out, you need to move m and n outside of the for loop, and increment them, instead of resetting them to the same thing every time you run your loop - re-checking the same numbers 987 times won't get you very far ;)

But also remember, with slices, the range is from (including) the first index, up to *but not including* the last index. Try it out:

```
string = '12345'
print(string[1:4])

--> 234
```

`'5'` is at the fourth index, but it is not printed.
If you want 13 digits after n, m will actually have to be **13**, not 12. This way, indices 0 through 12 are printed, which are 13 digits.

Finally, instead of just printing the values, you can add a bit of code to check it for you, and only print if the result is higher than the others, like this

```
if product > highest:
    highest = product
    print('new largest product:', product)
```

Good luck with the rest of Project Euler! :)

Comment: Would there be a quicker way, involving not printing numbers which had zeroes in, such as `if i == 0: continue`

Comment: If one of the numbers (x in your second for loop) is 0, yes you want to skip it. But use `break`, not `continue`, to stop iterating through that set of numbers

Comment: doesn't break break it out of the entire loop, I tried and it just gives me 0

Comment: Well if there is a zero in the digits, then it's pointless running the rest of the loop, because the product is 0